# Do I need to paste open source license information at the top of my webpage?

Tags: javascript, licensing

I'm developing a JavaScript application that uses several open source JavaScript projects.  All their licenses have a phrase like "You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License".  Does this mean I need to make a massive HTML comment at the top of my webpage with all the licences of the software that I use?

Comment: I think this should perhaps be migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ since "Software law" is listed in the faq as a topic.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Also, this question isn't definitively answerable without knowing exactly which licenses you're using.

Comment: Migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/41617/do-i-need-to-paste-open-source-license-information-at-the-top-of-my-webpage/41618#41618

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing which particular licenses it's hard to be definitive, but for most licenses you only need to put the notice in the source code itself (so you can put in HTML comments, or comments in your javascript code that requires these other libraries), and if the license is long, you can put a link in the source code and say "license available here".

Answer (score 0):

Usually not.  Usually licenses involve just keeping the copyright comments in the source files or as html comments on your page source code if it's directly on the page and not in an included file.  But it depends on the license. I've never seen a license that demanded that though..